# RewriteCond with REQUEST_URI not working like I want

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have an URL like this: `www.mydomain.com/file/a-file.pdf`

What I want is if my REQUEST_URI start by this: `/file/` then file.php (which is in the root directory) should handle the request. But if the URL is like this `www.mydomain.com/files/a-file.pdf`, no rewrite should be done.

I've done this but it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file/
RewriteRule .* file.php [L]
```

If I remove the last / on the first line, it's working but `www.mydomain.com/files/a-file.pdf` is also rewrite.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are these rules? In vhost config? in an htaccess file? Where is the htaccess file?

Comment: in an htaccess which is in the root directory. And the file directory doesn't exist, but the files one does.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your error logs when you try to go to `www.mydomain.com/file/a-file.pdf`?

Comment: No but the browser download my file.php

Comment: By download, you mean you see the contents of the php file instead of php executing the file?

Comment: Exactly, that's what happen.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with mod_rewrite or url rewriting. You need to setup a php handler for your php files because they are not being executed.

Comment: Like I say, if I set my rules like this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file (without the last slash), my php file is executed. What do you mean by setting up a php handler ?

Comment: Handlers are what handles files, like php. There is no way a rewrite rule can prevent php from getting executed unless something else is also affecting the request.

Comment: Any idea what it could be ?

Comment: No, but you can use [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) in your vhost config to debug this

Comment: I did but not enough... My problem is solve, an other rule was in cause. I believed the L flag were stopping the other rules to be executed but apparently not. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simpliest would be ignoring requests, which does match real files. Extend as follows

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file
RewriteRule .* file.php [L]
```

This assumes, your /files/a-file.pdf is a real file.

Comment: Since I asked this, I moved to nginx. So I can't test your answer but I will assume it is correct.